# Restoring page scroll position with jQuery is not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please find the more details about this as below:

On page one button is present (middle of the page) and when user clicks on that I want to restore the scroll at same position. I am using below solution for that and it is working fine in Chrome and FF but not working in IE.

```
// using window scroll because button is present in-between the page and I want the current position of the page
$(window).scroll( function(){
     var curPosition= $(window).scrollTop();
     setPagePosition(curPosition);
}); 

// on button click passing position                         
var setPagePosition = function (pos){
 $('.buttons a').click( function() {
  $(window).scrollTop(pos);
 });
};
```

In IE facing below issue:
Scroll going to top first and then coming back on same position.

Comment: <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1">
Try adding this line in the head section

Comment: what version of IE you are using ?

Comment: It is not working in any of the IE version. IE 9 10 11.

Comment: @mahi, it is already there

Comment: Try `$('html, body')` not `window`.

Comment: @evolutionxbox tried that also still not working.